# nodejs Error: Cannot find module '.-audio'

Tags: node.js

```
Error: Cannot find module '.-audio'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Stage_ete_2018_XperMedia\2eme stage\transcription-service-master\bin\lib\job.js:6:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
```

I already did :
npm install
npm install -audio

then after executing a google-cloud Error pop up and so on, if install one module the other pop up.

Comment: Please add the code as well where the error is happening. In this case, `job.js` I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm install -audio
```

This does nothing, it ignores non existing options that start with a `-`. NPM also does not give an error, as I tried with -something_that_does_exists_for_sure as an option.

I guess you want to install the audio package: https://github.com/audiojs/audio

```
npm install audio
+ audio@1.2.0
added 2 packages in 1.97s
```

It should read that it added two packages, I think you didnt install it yet.

Also I do not understand the `.-` in your error:

> Error:Cannot find module '.-audio'

Below is how the code example looks like in the [audio package readme](https://github.com/audiojs/audio). See it has no dots, nor minus symbols.

```
const Audio = require('audio')

Audio.load('./sample.mp3').then(audio =>
  audio
    .trim()
    .normalize()
    .fade(.5)
    .fade(-.5)
    .save('sample-edited.wav')
)
```

I guess you also need to remove those from your code. Dots are only needed if you want to require files from a certain directory, not for packages installed with NPM.

Comment: thank you  for your answer ,
but i did : npm install audio , and it didn't work , i even disactivate my Antivirus but no answer, after installing the audio pack i get the same error with 'node-ffprobe' module and if i install it the audio podule problem will come back and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this once,

- Remove `node_modules` folder from your project directory
- `npm install`
- `npm install <your_package_name> --save`

Comment: i did it for audio alone and for all the packages together and it didn't work